# From where is my Azure App Service fetching app settings?

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, appsettings

I have a .NET 6 web API that I deploy to Azure App Service using GitHub actions.

My web API contains 3 app settings files:

- appsettings.json
- appsettings.development.json
- appsettings.production.json

As far as I know, these files are usually used locally for development and testing purposes.

When the web app is deployed, it runs correctly and reads all values (somehow) from app settings. However, the "Application Settings" in the Azure Portal in the Configuration settings are empty. This is confusing me because I can't find out from where these app settings are being read.

This is my GitHub action YAML:

```yaml
name: API CI/CD

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: test    # set this to the name of your Azure Web App
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '6.0'                 # set this to the .NET Core version to use

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: Set up dependency caching for faster builds
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish  Test.Api -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

This is my program.cs:

```csharp
var builder        = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.RegisterApiVersioning();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.RegisterOptions(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.RegisterServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.RegisterSwagger();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(maksCorsPolicy);
app.ConfigureSwagger();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.Run();
```

I tried to change a value in my appsettings.production.json, and it was taken into account when I deployed. This confused me even more since I still can't see any app setting on the Azure Portal, but the application is finding it.

I tried searching on GitHub and on my app service for any configuration that tells my app to read these JSON files without any luck.

I am expecting my app not to find these app settings.

Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is reading your `appsettings.json` file even when deployed. If you right click and select `Properties` for your `appsettings.{env}.json` files, you'll see that they are set to:

```
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: If Newer
```

This means that the files will be sent along with your deployment.

Azure App Services do not actually populate the `Configuration` view from these settings, you have to set them yourself. (Or use a deployment action to set them via API).

In any case, if you manually set a new setting in your Azure AppService with the correct name, this will override whatever is contained in your `appsettings.json` files.

Make sure that, when creating the settings in Azure, you're careful to follow the correct naming conventions:

- Linux App Services will need `__` as a separator, so, for example: `Credentials__APIKey`
- Windows App Services will use `:` as a separator, so, for example: `Credentials:APIKey`

You can read more about the naming [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal)

Note that you can also use a `JSON` view to perform bulk modifications to your Configuration values inside Azure Portal by clicking on `Advanced Edit`

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear and precise.